# how to set up a new rails program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've heard a lot about rails, what is it and how does it work?

Comment: Did you try visiting http://rubyonrails.org/ ?

Answer (score 7):

Rails is a **web application framework**.

To be precise, it's a *generative framework* - meaning that it has tools that generate templated code and a templated project setup.

**Getting started**

After you've installed ruby (the language), rubygems (the ruby package management system) and rails (the web framework), you can just type `rails helloworldapp` and rails will generate a skeleton project in a new subdirectory called `helloworldapp`. To run the app, just move to the `helloworldapp` directory and type `ruby script/server` and you should get a minimal app running locally on port 3000.

It works well because you have almost zero plumbing to do to get a new project working - unlike the configuration nightmare of most Java frameworks.

**Download it and install it using the instructions here:** http://rubyonrails.org/

Try following this **tutorial:** http://guides.rails.info/getting_started.html

Comment: +1 for the "what is it and how does it work?"  But to completely answer the question, edit to include:

    'rails <application_name>'

Answer (score 2):

To start a new rails project after having it installed, it's quite easy.

```
rails <project name>
```

I'd recommend that you start by reading the rails guides, the first one being [getting started with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
It'll explain you all the basics to start programming in Ruby with Rails.